# Embedded system Build-system to use debian pbuilder

Tags: build, openwrt, buildroot, openembedded, pbuilder

As we know, **buildroot** and **openEmbedded** are major build systems for embedded system. Could anyone share what pbuilder is? Does it appropriate to be used in building embedded system? Could any expert share your experiences? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in pbuilder's [documentation](https://pbuilder.alioth.debian.org/#introduction):

> pbuilder stands for Personal Builder, and it is an automatic Debian
>   Package Building system for personal development workstation
>   environments.

You can create your own `*.deb` files with the help of `pbuilder`. But for the root file system you'll need another framework. Take a look at [ELBE project](https://elbe-rfs.org/). It also has [support for pbuilder](https://elbe-rfs.org/docs/sphinx/devel_elbe-3.0/elbe-pbuilder.html).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know wether buildroot support pbuilder?

Comment: @FrancisHu BR doesn't support pbuilder. These are different universes. pbuilder is a tool to package Debian's packets and BR creates a root files system from scratch using special recipes.